# how to sort a column and group them on pandas?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I am new on pandas. I try to sort a column and group them by their numbers.

```
df = pd.read_csv("12Patients150526 mutations-ORIGINAL.txt", sep="\t", header=0)
samp=df["SAMPLE"]

samp
Out[3]: 
0        11
1         2
2         9
3         1
4         8
5         2
6         1     
7         3
8        10
9         4
10        5
     ..
53157    12
53158     3
53159     2
53160    10
53161     2
53162     3
53163     4
53164    11
53165    12
53166    11
Name: SAMPLE, dtype: int64

#sorting
grp=df.sort(samp)
```

This code does not work. Can somebody help me about my problem, please.

How can I sort and group them by their numbers?

Comment: Note that sorting is different for a series and dataframe.  Above you have a series whereas @JianxunLi's answer has a dataframe.  When you do `samp=df['SAMPLE']` you are creating a series.  Easiest solution is probably to do as in answer (sort dataframe) and then convert to series.  There are other ways too, depends on what you want.

Comment: easiest way for you might just be `df = df.sort('SAMPLE')['SAMPLE']`

Comment: @JohnE thank you, it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort `df` based on a particular column, use `df.sort()` and pass column name as parameter.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
# ===========================
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,1000), columns=['SAMPLE'])
df

     SAMPLE
0         6
1         1
2         4
3         4
4         8
5         4
6         6
7         3
..      ...
992       3
993       2
994       1
995       2
996       7
997       4
998       5
999       4

[1000 rows x 1 columns]

# sort
# ======================
df.sort('SAMPLE')

     SAMPLE
310       1
710       1
935       1
463       1
462       1
136       1
141       1
144       1
..      ...
174       9
392       9
386       9
382       9
178       9
772       9
890       9
307       9

[1000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: thanks for answer but I am not asking that. You create random numbers and put them into sample column. My question is that, I have a column called "sample", I read it from csv file. I try to sort and group that column, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: @kant I just updated the answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I am reading sample column from a csv file. how can I sort the sample column while I am reading it from file. I am asking that :)  and I understand your code, but I can not modify it to my situation.

Comment: @JianxunLi  I think he has a series not dataframe

Comment: @kant you can't sort while reading from csv.  Have to do it after reading it in.